# Can't hide quickfix before executing makeprg

Tags: autocmd, quickfix, makeprg

I'm trying to hide the quickfix window while building, so that it doesn't show outdated info.

I can, of course, execute `:ccl` at any time to close quickfix. Additionally, I've used autocmd to call a function `BeforeQuickFix` which is successfully executed when prior to the execution of `makeprg`:

```
"hide quickfix when re-compiling
function BeforeQuickFix()
    :ccl
    :echom "hello test"
endfunction

autocmd QuickFixCmdPre * :call BeforeQuickFix()
```

However, while I see "hello test" printed prior to the execution of makeprg, the quickfix window never closes.

I've also tried to clear its contents instead with `:cexpr []`, but puzzlingly that also has no effect:

```
"hide quickfix when re-compiling
function BeforeQuickFix()
    :noautocmd cexpr []
endfunction

autocmd QuickFixCmdPre * :call BeforeQuickFix()
```

I'm sure I can manually hack at `makeprg` to get it to do what I want, but there has to be a cleaner way than that, right?